# How to log matrixes through a for loop into a text file as they would be printed in the Julia REPL?

Tags: julia

Considering the following loop:

```
julia> for i=1:3
         display(rand(2,2))
       end
2×2 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.338792  0.60386
 0.754133  0.357847
2×2 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.892743   0.728652
 0.0496951  0.44425
2×2 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.397286  0.779437
 0.311107  0.726685
```

I want to log this into a text file and my expected content in the text file is:

```
2×2 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.338792  0.60386
 0.754133  0.357847
2×2 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.892743   0.728652
 0.0496951  0.44425
2×2 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.397286  0.779437
 0.311107  0.726685
```

Note that the `2×2 Matrix{Float64}:` piece can be replaced with an empty line as well. I tried:

```
julia> using DelimitedFiles

julia> for i=1:3
         mat = rand(2,2)
         display(mat)
         writedlm("output.txt", mat)
       end
2×2 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.451093  0.154907
 0.168872  0.955592
2×2 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.688501  0.451259
 0.984798  0.570832
2×2 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.697317   0.882904
 0.0414643  0.907534
```

But the result is:

```
0.6973172179110919      0.8829040665300615
0.041464280519257546    0.9075339047610297
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [documentation for the `Base.Multimedia.display` method](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/io-network/#Base.Multimedia.display) says:

> If you want REPL-like text output that is guaranteed to go to `stdout`, use `show(stdout, "text/plain", x)` instead.

```
julia> M = rand(2,2)
2×2 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.0795215  0.229778
 0.484715   0.610577

julia> show(stdout, "text/plain", M)
2×2 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.0795215  0.229778
 0.484715   0.610577
```

You can use `show` to output to any `IO` object, so to write to a file:

```
julia> open("test.txt", "w") do io
           show(io, "text/plain", M)
       end

julia> open(io -> read(io, String), "test.txt")
"2×2 Matrix{Float64}:\n 0.0795215  0.229778\n 0.484715   0.610577"
```

The second argument of the [`Base.Multimedia.show` method](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/base/io-network/#Base.show-Tuple%7BIO,%20Any,%20Any%7D) is the MIME type to use when showing the object. This allows programmers to change how objects are serialized to different displays or file types depending on the target. The [documentation for pretty-printing](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1/manual/types/#man-custom-pretty-printing) will tell you how to extend these methods for different MIME types if necessary.

Comment: It's beautiful! Thank you so much. ❤ The main advantage of your proposed method is that it doesn't depend on the dimension of the array! The exact thing that I needed.

Answer (score 0):

The following approach works (However, this is not dynamic and only works for matrixes not for Arrays with any number of dimensions):

```
julia> function logmat(mat; path="output.txt")
         output_file = open(path, "a+")
         rows, cols = size(mat)
         # Write the matrix header
         println(output_file, "$rows×$cols Matrix{$(eltype(mat))}:")

         # Write the matrix row by row
         for row in 1:rows
             println(output_file, join(mat[row, :], "\t"))
         end

         # Write a newline to separate matrices
         println(output_file)
         close(output_file)
       end
logmat (generic function with 1 method)

julia> for i = 1:3
         mat = rand(2, 2)
         display(mat)
         logmat(mat)
       end
2×2 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.621561  0.333054
 0.956541  0.190905
2×2 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.149033   0.221495
 0.0643089  0.226895
2×2 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.789052  0.359041
 0.718996  0.410907
```

The text file contains:

```
2×2 Matrix{Float64}:
0.6215610365801023  0.3330544919075369
0.956540554411728   0.19090523866322373

2×2 Matrix{Float64}:
0.14903303721118577 0.22149546877853954
0.06430885375459938 0.2268953803244973

2×2 Matrix{Float64}:
0.7890523089417573  0.3590414346272712
0.7189956435893533  0.4109067995496086
```